# Android Volley: CalledFromWrongThreadException when uploading an image as String

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm trying to upload an image as String to my server using Volley in Android.

ONLY on older devices I get a CalledFromWrongThreadException. The code works perfectly on newer devices (Android 7+).

Error-Message:

> E/Volley: [231] NetworkDispatcher.processRequest: Unhandled exception android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

My POST-Request:

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() { ...

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                ...
                params.put("png", BitMapToString(cropImageView.getCroppedImage()));
                return params;
            }...



public String BitMapToString(Bitmap bitmap){
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, baos);
    byte [] b=baos.toByteArray();
    String temp=Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting the image outside the request solved the problem!

```
final Bitmap imageBitmap = cropImageView.getCroppedImage();

//REQUEST using imageBitmap below
```